# php variable in to JSON object

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter

i'm doing this in codeigniter

**here is my php switch - case part**

```
case 'check':
$balance = $this->Model_transactions->getUserBalance($this->input->post('userId'));
$needToPay = floatval($this->input->post('tuitionRate')) / 2; // 50%
if ($balance >= $needToPay) {
$results = '{"Result": "OK";"Balance":'.$balance.'}';
}
break;
```

**here is the json code**

```
$.ajax({
url: base_url + "api/hires/check/?callback=?",
type: "POST",
dataType: "jsonp",
data: {
userId: $(".navigation").data("login"),
tuitionRate: t.find("#txt-hire-rate").val()
}
}).done(function (a) {
if (a) if ("OK" != a.Result) {
alert (a.Balance);
```

what i want is to use php $balance variable in my jQuery. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to build the string literal, instead, construct an array and use `json_encode`

```
$results = json_encode(array('Result' => 'OK', 'Balance' => $balance), true);
```

Then return it when you're ready.

```
return $results;
```

Comment: got it Thank you! but how can i use this in jquery.
here what i'm trying to do.

.done(function (a) {
var data = $.parseJSON(a);
alert (data.Result);

Answer (score 1):

Edit your php script

```
case 'check':
$balance = $this->Model_transactions->getUserBalance($this->input->post('userId'));
$needToPay = floatval($this->input->post('tuitionRate')) / 2; // 50%
if ($balance >= $needToPay) {
$data = array(
  'Result' => 'OK',
  'Balance' => $balance 
);
echo json_encode($data);
}
break;
```

Edit your jQuery Script

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: '<?php echo base_url()."api/hires/check/?callback=?";?>',
 dataType: 'json',
 data:{userId: $(".navigation").data("login"),
 tuitionRate: t.find("#txt-hire-rate").val()},
 success: function(data){
            if(data.Result != "OK"){
                    alert(data.Balance);
            }
           }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

php switch - case part

```
    case 'check':
    $balance = $this->Model_transactions->getUserBalance($this->input->post('userId'));
    $needToPay = floatval($this->input->post('tuitionRate')) / 2; // 50%
    if ($balance >= $needToPay) {
    $results = '{"Result": "OK";"Balance":'.$balance.'}';

    // add this in your code 
    <script>
       document.getelementbyId('balance').innerHTML=$balance;
    <script>
    }
    break;
    ?>
    <div id='balance' style='display:none;'></div> // added in the code
```

json code

```
var bal=$(#balance).html(); // use this variable where you want to
$.ajax({
url: base_url + "api/hires/check/?callback=?",
type: "POST",
dataType: "jsonp",
data: {
userId: $(".navigation").data("login"),
tuitionRate: t.find("#txt-hire-rate").val()
}
}).done(function (a) {
if (a) if ("OK" != a.Result) {
alert (a.Balance);
```

I did changes in php code and added the variable in js which can be used anywhere in js you want to.